# Inconsistent finite difference scheme for linear inhomogeneous diffusion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation, finite-differences

I'm working on a finite difference scheme to simulate my model equations. As part of it I have to discretise the linear inhomogeneous diffusion operator:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( D(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)$$

Using a central difference on the outer derivative I obtain:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( D(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) \bigg|_r^n 
\approx \frac{1}{2h} \left[ \left(D\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)\bigg|_{r+1}^n - \left(D\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)\bigg|_{r-1}^n\right]$$
Subsequently applying a forward and backward difference to the two derivatives at $x_{r-1}^n$ and $x_{r+1}^n$ gives me the following approximation:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( D(x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) \bigg|_r^n  &\approx \frac{1}{2h^2} \left[ D_{r+1}^n\left(u_{r+1}^n - u_r^n\right) - D_{r-1}^n\left(u_r^n - u_{r-1}^n\right) \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2h^2} \left[D_{r-1}^n u_{r-1}^n - \left(D_{r-1}^n + D_{r+1}^n \right) u_r^n +D_{r+1}^n u_{r+1}^n \right]
\end{align}

However, if I now let $D=1$ everywhere so that I go back to homogeneous linear diffusion this gives:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} \bigg|_r^n \approx \frac{1}{2h^2} \left[u_{r-1}^n - 2 u_r^n + u_{r+1}^n \right],$$
which is 1/2 times what one would expect.

I suspect there's something wrong in the way I mix central, forward and backward differences, but I don't see what. How can the factor of 1/2 be explained?

Thanks very much for your help!

Maxi

Answer (score 1):

You used a first order (one-sided) approximation of the first derivative in the second step; apparently this is not enough. How about

$
\partial_x (D \partial_x) u |_r
\approx
$

$
\frac1h
\left[ (D \partial_x u)_{r+1/2} - (D \partial_x u)_{r-1/2} \right]
\approx
$

$
\frac1h
\left[ \frac1h D_{r+1/2}(u_{r+1} - u_r) - \frac1h D_{r-1/2} (u_r - u_{r-1}) \right]
$

?

That gives the usual central finite difference when $D$ is constant.

Btw., your operator is a *linear inhomogeneous* diffusion operator *in divergence form*.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is there a deeper reason for why the first derivatives are not enough?
Thanks also for correcting the description. I'll correct it in the title.

Comment: @MaximilianStrobl: I'd say, the general reason (even if it is not deep) is the sensitivity of the derivative wrt perturbations of the function (because you divide by $h$). In this case, the "outer derivative" receives an inaccurate approximation of the function which is the "inner derivative".

Comment: @MaximilianStrobl: If you want to see what went wrong, substitute a second order Taylor series for $u(x)$ in your initial computation. Keep track of the residual error and you will see the inconsistency arise.